# Rspec feature specs not working with Devise sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I want to test that a user can log in and that a visitor can sign up. The log in works well but for sign up it is not working for some reason. This is my feature spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Devise interactions", type: :feature do
    let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:non_admin_user) }

    scenario "user logs in sucessfully" do
        visit new_user_session_path

        fill_in "Email", with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Log in"

        expect(page).to have_current_path "/"
    end

    scenario "user logs in unsuccesfully" do
        visit new_user_session_path

        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Log in"

        expect(page).to have_text('Invalid Email or password')
    end

    scenario "visitor signs up succesfully", js:true do
        visit new_user_registration_path

        fill_in "Username", with: "josem"
        fill_in "Email", with: "abcd@test.com"
        within ".user_password" do
            fill_in 'Password', with: 'testing'
        end
        within ".user_password_confirmation" do
            fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'testing'
        end

        #save_and_open_screenshot

        click_button "Sign up"

        #save_and_open_screenshot

        expect(page).to have_text('Welcome! You have signed up successfully.')
    end

    scenario "visitor signs up unsuccesfully" do
        visit new_user_registration_path

        fill_in "Username", with: "josem"
        fill_in "Email", with: "abcd"
        within ".user_password" do
            fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
        end
        within ".user_password_confirmation" do
            fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'password'
        end
        click_button "Sign up"

        expect(page).to have_text('Email is invalid')
    end
end
```

The third scenario:

```
scenario "visitor signs up succesfully", js:true do
        visit new_user_registration_path

        fill_in "Username", with: "josem"
        fill_in "Email", with: "abcd@test.com"
        within ".user_password" do
            fill_in 'Password', with: 'testing'
        end
        within ".user_password_confirmation" do
            fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'testing'
        end

        #save_and_open_screenshot

        click_button "Sign up"

        #save_and_open_screenshot

        expect(page).to have_text('Welcome! You have signed up successfully.')
    end
```

Is the one that is not working. Been trying to debug:

1. Before the `Sign up` button is clicked, everything is written correctly
2. After the `Sign up` button is clicked, I only get an error of `Please review the problems below:` but it doesn´t say what type of error (there shouldn't be any error since the validations are all successful).
3. When I go to my Rails app and try to sign up manually, every time I have an error, it will point it out but it doesn't in the spec.

Since the log in is working, I doubt it is an error from the Devise config and I can´t find out why. Any ideas on why is it happening? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I feel the error that you are getting is not from the device. Because devise doesn't have any error with message `Please review the problems below`. Possibly the error is from the [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) gem which you might be using(check your Gemfile.lock). **simple_form** gem has the same error notification which you have mentioned. Please refer to the code [Please review the problems below](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/0f20705fafaec3376d6030171774d1ce0509bfae/lib/simple_form/error_notification.rb#L45).

Also, you can see the feature test log `tail -f log/test.log`.